# How do I use attributes on fields on a custom derive macro?

Tags: struct, rust, attributes, rust-macros

I'm writing my derive macro:

```
use proc_macro::{self, TokenStream};
#[proc_macro_derive(MyMacro, attributes(my_attr))]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
  ...
  TokenStream::from(my_generated_code)
}
```

with the attributes which will be used like:

```
use my_crate::MyMacro;
#[derive(MyMacro)]
#[my_attr(foo)]
struct MyStruct {
  // some fields
  #[my_attr(abc)]
  a: i32,
}
```

But this snip leads to:

```
error: cannot find attribute `my_attr` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:7
   |
6  |     #[my_attr(abc)]
   |       ^^^^^^^
```

This is insanely weird because the attribute on struct is working well. Also I tried to change `struct`  on `enum` and then field annotation has worked for some reason

May it be the problem of `rustc`, `proc_macro` version? `rustc` version: `rustc 1.61.0-nightly (c5cf08d37 2022-03-30)`

Macro-crate's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
syn = {version= "1.0", features = ["full", "extra-traits"]}
quote = "1.0"
```

I found the same problem: [issue](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-i-create-a-custom-attribute-that-will-be-consumed-by-a-custom-derive-macro/43116), but the solution isn't clear at all and it's solved so I can't ask for some explanations

Comment: Can't reproduce locally.

Comment: Have exactly the same problem right now. Will either solve it and post solution here or make reproducible sample

Comment: This happens when syntax tree of source structure MyStruct is copied into resulting token stream (maybe with some modification like changing name, replacing some types, etc). The attributes "my_attr" are also copied into generated structure, which is not under "#[derive(MyMacro)] anymore. So the #[my_attr] attributes are not valid *in scope of generated structure*